# SQL query help correctness and compatibility

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I want a set of records in a table to be concatenated as follows.

```
select vResult + '\n' AS [text()]  
from ORC 
where iorderid  = 310714 
order by iSetID 
FOR XML PATH(''), ELEMENTS
```

I am not sure if this query has any limitation of size of data or version of SQL.

Can you help me if the above query can run on SQL2005 and onwards? also will I get any size limitation by using this query?

In case, can you correct the query for size limitation free query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would cast as varchar(max) rather than text().  varchar(max) has a 2GB limit per result, which ought to be enough for most cases.  SQL 2005 and up support it.

```
select cast(vResult + '\n' AS varchar(max))
from ORC 
where iorderid  = 310714 
order by iSetID 
FOR XML PATH(''), ELEMENTS
```

Comment: updated it now.  Not sure if you wanted the column to literally be called 'text()' or what - as it is, it should work.